# ASP.NET MVC single thread action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

are there any possibility in MVC framework to make  some singe action of MVC controller process requests one by one like queue. Like singleton single thread in WCF.

Comment: Why don't you use a queue as you suggested? You can use ConcurrentQueue(T) Class (thread safe).

Answer (score 2):

Even if that's possible, I don't recommend it.
Each request would be "stuck" waiting for the previous one to get handled. 
You would get timeouts as a result...

What I suggest is to use a [ConcurrentQueue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx) which is thread safe, and queue each request.

It seems that maybe you even don't need a queue. Just keep the state of your user somehow, so his/her next call would be dependent on the first call.

Comment: I can't. I need return result of action. Are there any nice MVC framework solution or only possibility is a locks in my code?

Comment: Why? You need a synchronous operation? What's the scenario? Sounds like you're architecture is wrong.

Comment: In simple words we have a partner that send two requests for one item concurrently. I need process first request and ignore second. Also I need return some error if I have some inner problem.

Comment: The one who uses your function, needs to have like a status which tells him/her whether to continue on with the next action. It doesn't contradicts my answer.

Comment: Your design is not good. You need to keep the state somehow of who ever calls your action. I don't think that you even need a queue at all.